# Как получить id каждого блока и закрыть их?

Tags: javascript

Такой вопрос:

У меня есть уведомления которые появляются в углу экрана, их я генерирую с помощью js чтобы их было несколько и они могли появляться друг под другом. Но не могу их закрыть с помощью кнопки закрыть.

Вот код:

```js
function notify(type,message){
  (()=>{
    var n = document.createElement("div");
    var id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,10);
    n.setAttribute("id",id);
    n.classList.add("notification",type);
    n.classList.add("fade_out");
    n.innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById("notification-area").appendChild(n);
    setTimeout(()=>{
    var notifications = document.getElementById("notification-area").getElementsByClassName("notification");
      for(var i=0;i<notifications.length;i++){
        if(notifications[i].getAttribute("id") == id){
          notifications[i].remove();
          break;
        }
      }
    },50000);
  })();
}
```

Появляется и закрывается сам автоматически через 5 сек. Но как закрыть с помощью кнопки?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#notification-area span', function () {

var a = $('.notification').attr('id');

 if (a) {
    alert(a);
    }

});
```

Отслеживаю событие по клику и никак не могу закрыть нужный мне блок с уведомлением.Как можно сделать? Может кто помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('.notification').remove();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Comment: @timursites Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.